# Auto GPU selection based on program running

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon, selection

I have two GPUs, a GTX 960 and a RX 480. I wanna to use 960 to play games but use 480 to decode video with MPC-BE + madVR. How can I achieve that with a auto selection powered by what program I'm on focus/running?

EDIT: both card runs on a desktop computer

Comment: This setup boggles my mind. You could try to look into your driver settings for it. As for MPC and such you would have to look into the application settings (likely). Also check this [How To Geek: How to Force Graphics Options in PC Games with NVIDIA, AMD, or Intel Graphics](http://www.howtogeek.com/175281/how-to-force-graphics-options-in-pc-games-with-nvidia-amd-or-intel-graphics/). Otherwise what have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to put the Nivdia card in slot one so the game most likely will use it first. However, even in force setting in MPC, hardware decoding wont work properly, where I stuck. I tried to use the physical switch on the motherboard the switch which card to use but need restart the whole machine and rewire the cable which is time consuming. Now I only use the AMD card and disable the Nvidia card with the motherboard switch.

Comment: @Seth the link you provide is more about performance tweak, but I need to select a specific GPU to run the program

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I only skipped around it. Essentially your setup (from what I can tell) is pretty uncommon. Usually you would have options within the driver and you might actually be able to force the applications by setting up specific profiles in each driver. What switch are you talking about? For Nvidia you would have an option in the context menu - if it were a [Optimus setup](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/infraworks-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-force-your-laptop-to-Run-with-Graphics-Processor-vs-the-default-Integrated-Graphics-for-InfraWorks.html).

Comment: @Seth Oh I forgot to mention that my computer is a DIY desktop, not laptop. My bad.

Comment: That is clear from the components you're using. It was just an example of when two different graphics card are not uncommon and when you would have a driver that reasonably supports them. Further more, as the RX 480 is the [more powerful card](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-RX-480-vs-GeForce-GTX-960),  don't really get why you wouldn't use that card for gaming. Did you try to setup profiles for applications just one of the cards? What does your display setup (connection wise and number) look like?

Comment: @Seth Thanks for your advice, now I switched to RX 480 and took out 960 from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Seth recommendation, now I switched to RX 480 and took out GTX 960 out of my system.